# WebGL not found in latest version of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

When I go to https://kuula.co/ I get the following popup:

> There seems to be an issue with WebGL in your browser. Please reload the page or restart the browser

When I go to https://www.360cities.net/ I get the following error:

> Adobe Flashplayer or HTML5 Browser with WebGL or CSS3D support required!

I'm running the latest version of Chrome (96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

A number of tutorials suggest going to chrome://flags. Here's what I see when I do that:

[image]

Those options don't align up with any of the tutorials I'm seeing online.

My video cards are as follows:

- Intel UHD Graphics (driver version 27.20.100.9749; driver date 6/24/2021)
- NVIDIA Quadro P520 (driver version 30.0.14.7141; driver date 7/12/2021)

https://pastebin.com/7YJXhcy8 is what `chrome://gpu` says.

Additionally, hardware acceleration is enabled as the following screenshot shows:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What graphics card do you have? What driver? It may be that webgl requires an up to date device.

Comment: @Mokubai - my laptop has two - Intel UHD Graphics and NVIDIA Quadro P520. idk how to tell which one I'm using. The driver version for the Intel is 27.20.100.9749 and the driver date is 6/24/2021. The driver version for the NVIDIA is 30.0.14.7141 and the driver date is 7/12/2021.

Comment: Okay what do you see in the browser if you go to `chrome://gpu`? Can you make sure that hardware acceleration is enabled  per the "Enabling hardware acceleration on Chrome" at https://appuals.com/fix-webgl-is-not-supported/

Comment: @Mokubai - https://pastebin.com/7YJXhcy8 is what `chrome://gpu` says. I can do a screenshot, too, if that'd help - a screenshot would highlight things in various colors. And yes, hardware acceleration is enabled as described in that link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y52JQ.png It was like that when I opened up that page so it's been doing hardware acceleration, presumably for a while.